# How can I detect touch in custom MKAnnotationView? ios7

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

This not works

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Tried add this

```
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[User class]])
     {
         NSString * annotationIdentifier = @"UserAnnotationIdentifier";
         CustomAnnotationView * customAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
         if (!customAnnotationView)
         {
             customAnnotationView = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
             UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
             [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                     action:@selector(calloutTapped:)];
             [customAnnotationView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

and then

```
    -(void) calloutTapped:(id) sender {
       id<MKAnnotation> annotation = ((MKAnnotationView*)sender.view).annotation;
```

ERROR: property view not found on object of type __strong id

This works, but not always

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
 {
NSLog(@"didSelectAnnotationView\n");

 }

 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
 {
NSLog(@"didDeselectAnnotationView\n");
 }
```

Where I bad?

Comment: "This not works" - didn't you forgot to set the mapView delegate to the object where you implement this method?

Comment: yep, map not reacts on this.

Comment: well, you also have to add effectively the callout to the annotation - it does not show it by default. Try to set ` canShowCallout` to YES in your MKAnnotationView. By default it will show an (i) icon but you can customize it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.And make sure you set the MKMapViewDelegate to that class.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[myCustomAnnotaionClass class]])
        {
            //your programming logic here
        }
    }
```